# How can I find where my JAVA_HOME environment variable has been set?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

This is driving me crazy, I know that I have a JAVA_HOME environment variable set somewhere, but I have checked all the usual places  -~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc but I can't find it.

Is there a way in OSX or Linux to check where an environment variable is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`

Or `/etc/rclocal` or any of those `/etc/rc*.d` or `/etc/rc*` directories.